# Integer to two digit Hexadecimal in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, hex, number-formatting

I have a hex byte array

`byte hex= {0xAA, 0x55, 0x00, 0x00}`

I also have an integer value lets say

`int val= 10;`

Now I want to convert the integer value to 4 digit hex value like 0x000A and store it in the hex[3] and hex[2] of the first and last  2 digits respectively.

For example:

```
int val=10;
//in hex val=0x000A
msb= 0x00;
lsb= 0x0A;
hex[3]= msb;
hex[2]= lsb;
//so my final hex array will be 
hex[]={0xAA, 0x55, 0x0A, 0x00}

//here is another example:
int val=300;
//in hex val=0x012C
msb= 0x01;
lsb= 0x2C;
hex[3]= msb;
hex[2]= lsb;
//so my final hex array will be 
hex[]={0xAA, 0x55, 0x2C, 0x01}
```

How can I implement in C or C++?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have an array of hex-values, it's still an array of `byte` (some integer), no matter how you write it. `{0xAA, 0x55, 0x2C, 0x01}` is _exactly_ the same as `{170, 85, 44, 1}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple

```
int val = 10;
int msb = val/256;
int lsb = val%256;
hex[3] = msb;
hex[2] = lsb;
```

Doesn't work for negative integers or integers with more that 16 significant bits. But I guess you don't care about that.

There's a hint in your question that you have the common newbie misunderstanding that there's some fundamental difference between hexadecimal integers and decimal integers. There's isn't, all integers are of the same kind (which is normally binary). Decimal and hexadecimal are just different ways of **printing** integers not different ways the C++ language **represents** integers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are dealing with endianness here. [union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) might help

```
#include <iostream>

union U {
  uint32_t val;
  uint8_t hex[4];
};

int main() {
  U u{0x12345678};
  std::cout << std::hex << u.val << std::endl;
  for (const auto h : u.hex) {
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<uint32_t>(h) << std::endl;
  }
}
```